# Druid Group by Day of Week and Hour of Day

Tags: sql, druid

I am trying to find how to group by day of week, and also hour of day in Druid. I am relying on Druid documentation here: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/querying/sql.html, and all the following functions are from this page.

I know that Druid has a function `TIME_SHIFT(<timestamp_expr>, <period>, <step>, [<timezone>])` that can round down timestamp according to the period in ISO8601 standard, and then we can group by the rounded-down timestamp to achieve grouping by day time period we want.

1. However, what if I want to group by day of week so that I can sum up all the sales income received on all Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays,..., Sundays in a period of time? I know that there is a `TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, [<unit>, [<timezone>]])` function, and I may be able to achieve what I want by using this function and  = DOW (day of week) to transform each timestamp to a number (1 to 7) and then group by each of the extracted values. Is that correct?
2. And what if I want to group by hour of day? I don't see a unit "hour of day" in this manual.

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:
It seems to be working; however, is there a way to make it print out Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... instead of numbers from 1-7? I guess I can probably do some type of casting manually in the select block, but I am wondering if there is a better way? Thanks again!**

Comment: Wouldn't TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, HOUR) do that?

Comment: @tinazmu Oh that actually makes sense... I will try that and report back. Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be working; however, is there a way to make it print out Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... instead of numbers from 1-7? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't `TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, HOUR)` do that?

For day names, I believe you can use:

```
TIME_FORMAT(<timestamp_expr>, [<pattern>, [<timezone>]])
```

For pattern it seems you can use 'EEEE' (for full text form of day name).

Comment: Thank you! This is working. However, I am wondering if there is a way to make it show Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday... instead of 1-7? I guess I can probably do some type of casting manually in the select block, but I am wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: added a dayname option, try!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping year, month, day wise with Druid SQL

```
SELECT TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, 'DAY') AS dt, TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, 'MONTH') AS mon, TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, 'YEAR') AS yr, <AGGREGATION_FUNCTION>(<column_name>) AS agg_val
FROM <datasource_name>
GROUP BY TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, 'DAY'), TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, 'MONTH'), TIME_EXTRACT(<timestamp_expr>, 'YEAR')
```

Here, in many cases <timestamp_expr> is `__time`

This could be more better for grouping days of week too and renaming them as weeks days.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN int_dy=1 THEN 'Mon' 
            WHEN int_dy=2 THEN 'Tue' 
            WHEN int_dy=3 THEN 'Wed'
            WHEN int_dy=4 THEN 'Thu'
            WHEN int_dy=5 THEN 'Fri'
            WHEN int_dy=6 THEN 'Sat'
            WHEN int_dy=7 THEN 'Sun' 
            END AS wk_dy,
            *
FROM (
  SELECT TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'DOW') AS int_dy,
         TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'HOUR') AS hr
         TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'DAY') AS dt, 
         TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'MONTH') AS mn, 
         TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'YEAR') AS yr, 
         <AGG_Function>(<column_name>) AS agg_val
  FROM <datasource/table_name>
  WHERE __time BETWEEN '<start_dt>' and '<end_dt>'
  GROUP BY TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'HOUR'),
           TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'DOW'), 
           TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'DAY'), 
           TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'MONTH'), 
           TIME_EXTRACT(__time, 'YEAR')
  HAVING agg_val >= <threshold_val>
  ) AS t
ORDER BY yr, mon, dt, hr, agg_val DESC
```